# Control Link Description of a Wordpress link shared on Facebook

Tags: facebook, wordpress, hyperlink, meta

When we share a link directly on Facebook, and the link goes to a Wordpress blog, how can we control the text that Facebook will pull and use as the description for the shared link? Just go to facebook and paste or enter any Wordpress URL in, it will take the story of the first post on the front page as the description for that URL.

I've tried:

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo get_bloginfo ( 'description' );  ?>" />
```

and

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo get_bloginfo ( 'description' );  ?>" />
```

but it still does not get the right description on Facebook. Yes, I've set description for my site on Wordpress. Yes, the description is show on the site when I view source.

Thanks.

Comment: Run the [Facebook Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and let me know how that works out for you.

Comment: Ran that, Object Properties has correct "og:description:". Thanks.

Comment: Will add this as the answer, then. Please accept it once you see it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Facebook has its own Caching that can sometimes cause changes to your Meta Tags to never show up properly, even after adding or changing them.

Running the [Facebook Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) not only will tell you if something is wrong with your Meta Tags, but also will clear its cache of the target website's information so that its current information can be properly scraped.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done any facebook development, but looking at this [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/), it says

> The title and description tags are the minimum requirements for any preview, so make sure to include these two.

So maybe try including `<meta property="og:title" content="title" />` as well?